# Spark Scala - How to create new column for each group and then explode the column values in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataframe is like below
 Col names index, words

```
Index | words
one | {col1: a, col2: b}
one | {col1: c, col2: d}
two | {col1: a, col2: b}
two | {col1: e, col2: f}
```

I am looking output like below
Output df column names one,two

```
one | two
 {col1: a, col2: b} | {col1: a, col2: b}
 {col1: c, col2: d} | {col1: e, col2: f}
```

Any one please help me out on this one. I am using spark 1.5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that for every index value there would be two words you can use the below :

```
sqlContext.sql("select Index, collect_list(words)[0],collect_list(words)[1] from yourTable group by Index").show
```